# How to have multi turtlebot 3 in a real environment?

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ros and I'm having some problems and I hope someone can help me.

I want to use  2 "turtlebot3 burger"  at the same time in a real environment, in my nodes I have the control and at the end I have a topic "/cmd_vel" for each robot.

How can I make each robot subscribe to its respective "/cmd_vel", without conflicts?

I have read several topics about how to have several robots in a simulation environment like gaebo, and I have tried them and they work correctly, but I am not able to do the same with real robots.

Should I change something in the configuration of the robots?
Should I modify my launch file to have two ns groups and include a "turtlebot3_bringup" file?

Thanks in advance and any ideas or advice will be very helpful

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282060/how-to-have-multi-turtlebot-3-in-a-real-environment?/) by [carlosal24](https://answers.ros.org/users/33317/carlosal24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-07**:
Check out #q41433. Even though it's for a simulation (and old) it's still very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, it seems that I found a simple solution and that until now it works perfectly.

It works in turtlebot 2 and turtlebot 3, the simplest solution is that before performing the "bringup", add in the robot terminal

```
export ROS_NAMESPACE=Robot1
```

and then perform the bring up for the respective model of your robot, for example for the burger

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
```

Doing this with each one of the robots you have, you avoid conflicts in the topics. Even if you do not want to do this every time you start the robots, you can add the name in the bash of your robot.

In the robot terminal

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the name of the robot in the window

```
export ROS_NAMESPACE=NAME
```

You save it and finally in the terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

I hope that if someone has this problem, this information will be helpful

---

Originally posted by [carlosal24](https://answers.ros.org/users/33317/carlosal24/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-19**:
I think that this is ok if you're manually starting everything on your robot. If you want to use launch files remotely to start the nodes on your robot then I believe that the `.bashrc` is *not* used and you should use a separate `env-loader.sh` to load your environment variables.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-19**:
See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine